# Trouble with .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Please can somebody take a look at my .htaccess code to help identify what's wrong.

I am trying to amend all example.php, example.html and example.htm URL's to index.php?filename=example.html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^(index\.php) - [L]

   RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).(php|html|htm)$ index.php?filename=$1.html&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I enter a URL like example.html I'm taken to the default 404 and not index.php

Comment: Is that your complete .htaccess? I ran it in MAMP with *only* what you provided with no errors.

Comment: It is. I also created a .htaccess that only contained a 404 redirect just to test that the location and file is being used and that works but when I'm using only this .htaccess what I'm trying to achieve doesn't work : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. With this I'm being told it cannot find the URL I have entered as though it is not re-routing to index.php

Comment: Indicates multiple options for the resource that the client may follow. You may have multiple files that *could be* the resource in question, causing an ambiguity. What are you passing?

Comment: Ok all my page data is stored in a database and each entry has a filename field e.g. index.html, about.html, contact.html etc. I want all my hyperlinks to link to /index.html, /about.html etc. and then all those links are re-written as /index.php?filename=index.html or ?filename=about.html. Then I want to get the filename data, look it up in my database and pull in the data. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Thank you for that but my PDO statements are all working. They simply are having trouble being provided with the filename data. The .htaccess code above isn't re-routing to index.php but simply looking for the index.html file rather than index.php?filename=index.html

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, which is why I just roughed out the DB points... Point is to make sure you're providing it with what it needs. Try echoing your `$_GET['filename']` value and make sure that you're passing what you *expect* you're passing. I'm betting you're not.

Comment: If I remove my .htaccess file and use a full URL like /index.php?filename=index.html then everything works perfectly, so I'm simply trying to re-create /index.php?filename=index.html from /index.html

Comment: Try at the top of your index.php adding `echo $_GET['filename'];` and post what's displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using the apache .hatacces for a while,
But try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|img|js)($|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?filename=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Basically what you need is to be sure that the URL didn't have already index.php. You accomplish it with RewriteCond.

After you redirect all to index.php passing the filename as a parameter.

You can add more exception to the RewriteCond like on this example, all content with /css, /js, /img will not pass to this rule.

You can check this thread: [Using .htaccess to reroute all requests through index.php EXCEPT a certain set of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394123/using-htaccess-to-reroute-all-requests-through-index-php-except-a-certain-set-o) also

Comment: Ok this appears to be getting somewhere. When I use this I get a very odd behaviour where each time I refresh the page only some of my CSS is being used. Also it isn't finding my data based on the filename parameter thats passed but at least it's re-routung all requests to index.php for now.

Comment: you're not going to grab in the data from $1.html using this... if I'm understanding what it is you mean to do.

Comment: I just added new condition with exception to /css, /img and /js content. You can add more exceptions using this style. Hope it helps you.